# How to span a column equal to one and half column in html table

Tags: html, html-table

[In this image two columns are spanned equal to three columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXRzu.jpg)

[image]

How can I achieve this in my situation,

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Top</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Left</td>
    <td>Center</td>
    <td>Right</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Left</td>
    <td>Right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">Top</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Left</td>
                <td colspan="2">Center</td>
                <td colspan="2">Right</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Left</td>
                <td colspan="3">Right</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained the reasoning behind how the code works.